# Manually deleting HBase data

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I have a small dev cluster with an HBase installation.  My cluster's disk usage has filled to capacity so I need to delete some data, but I cannot start the regionservers.  They fail with the message in the logs:

```
File /hbase/.logs/<some file> could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

I presume because there is no room left in the cluster.

I am wondering, what can I manually delete (via hdfs) from HBase safely without causing any sort of metadata corruptions?

The areas taking up the most space in hdfs are

```
/hbase/.logs
/hbase/mytable
```

If I no longer care about the data in `mytable`, can I just delete it manually with

```
hadoop fs -rmr /hbase/mytable
```

or will HBase complain when it starts up next?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't recommended to delete tables directly via HDFS. Note that HBase stores data about the tables in various places (the .META. table , zookeeper, the .logs can contain uncommitted changes to your table) so if you do manual file deletions make sure to run hbase hbck to check and fix HBase's table.

A better way is to find what's wrong with the cluster , add a node etc. rather then do manual deletes